# C# Selenium XPATH Dynamic Button Select Based on Text in Span

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to select a button that is dynamically created based on the name of the person in the span and I am having trouble getting the XPATH syntax correct.  There would be several of these buttons dynamically created on the page so the identifier I need to use is the customer name.  Here is the HTML of the button.

```
<button id="172369678903-announce" name="172369678903" data-selected-address-id="172369678903" data-unit-ids="[&quot;miq://document:1.0/Contract/a:1.0/Unit:1.0/dc290763-6cce-46c5-a878-3b5b0e615740#35176ee2-51c5-479b-b63e-a2cc958a2de9&quot;]" data-url="/spr/returns/addressSelection/dc290763-6cce-46c5-a878-3b5b0e615740" class="a-button-text selected-address" type="button">
    <div class="a-column a-span12">
        <div class="a-row">
        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-text-left">
            <span class="a-text-bold">
        John Doe
            </span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="a-row">
        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-text-left">
            <span>
        20410 SOME STREET, WALNUT, CA, 91789-2435
            </span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="a-row">
        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-text-left">
            <span>
Phone number: 2813308004
            </span>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</button>
```

I have the information John Doe and that is how I need to be able to click on this item.  Here is the XPATH syntax I currently have but have tried many different forms of it.  The variable shipName contains the name John Doe in it.

```
var addyFinder = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button/span[contains(text(),'" + shipName.Trim() + "')]"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below XPath to select required `button` node:

```
"//button[normalize-space(.//span)='" + shipName.Trim() + "']"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned *there would be several of these buttons dynamically created on the page* and you *need to use the customer name*, so you can create a function and call the function with any of the *usernames* as follows:

- Function defination:

  ```
  public void click_user(string username)
  {
      driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='a-button-text selected-address' and contains(@data-url,'addressSelection')]//span[@class='a-text-bold'][normalize-space()='" + username + "']")).Click();
  }
  ```
- Calling the function:

  ```
  click_user("John Doe");
  //or
  click_user("Roro");
  ```